# capture numbers between two characters in R

Tags: regex, r

I need to capture cpu usage data from this string, in this cast cpu usage is 1.55. Values between - and %

```
 cpu<-c("CPU Usage: u814.13 s13.33 cu0 cs0 - 1.55% CPU load")
```

I have tried this:

```
as.numeric(gsub("^.*- ([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", cpu))
```

It is giving 1.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `sub(".*- ([0-9.]+)\\%.*", "\\1", cpu)` works fine for me. I guess you're just missing the period/dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([\d\.]+)% CPU.*$
```

You didn't include the decimal dot in the square brackets